# Making request for Shipping Rate sent to a Carrier Service

Tags: shopify

I am sending this request:

```
{ "carrier_service":
   { "name": "Test Provider",
     "callback_url": "callback_url",
     "format": "json",
     "service_discovery": true,
     "rate": {
             "origin": {
                 "country": "CA",
                 "postal_code": "K1S4J3",
                 "province": "ON",
                 "city": "Ottawa",
                 "name": "test name",
                 "address1": "520 Cambridge Street South",
                 "address2": "asas",
                 "address3": "sdsdsd",
                 "phone": "32323323434",
                 "fax": "3434343434",
                 "address_type": "sdsdsd",
                 "company_name": "test"
             },
             "destination": {
                 "country": "CA",
                 "postal_code": "K1S 3T7",
                 "province": "ON",
                 "city": "Ottawa",
                 "name": "Jason Normore",
                 "address1": "520 Cambridge Street South Apt. 5",
                 "address2": null,
                 "address3": null,
                 "phone": "7097433959",
                 "fax": null,
                 "address_type": null,
                 "company_name": null
             },
             "items": [
                 {
                     "name": "My Product 3",
                     "sku": "sdsdsdsd",
                     "quantity": 1,
                     "grams": 1000,
                     "price": 2000,
                     "vendor": "TestVendor",
                     "requires_shipping": true,
                     "taxable": true,
                     "fulfillment_service": "manual"
                 }
             ],
             "currency": "CAD"
         }
         }
      }
```

it's saying
you already have Test Provider set up for this shop
But when I remove carrier and make request once again it shows only

```
{"carrier_services":[{"active":true,"id":116379,"name":"Test Provider","service_discovery":true,"carrier_service_type":"api"}]}
```

But i need to get response like described here http://docs.shopify.com/api/carrierservice

```
{
         "rates": [
             {
                 "service_name": "canadapost-overnight",
                 "service_code": "ON",
                 "total_price": "1295",
                 "currency": "CAD",
                 "min_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400",
                 "max_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400"
             },
             {
                 "service_name": "fedex-2dayground",
                 "service_code": "1D",
                 "total_price": "2934",
                 "currency": "USD",
                 "min_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400",
                 "max_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400"
             },
             {
                 "service_name": "fedex-2dayground",
                 "service_code": "1D",
                 "total_price": "2934",
                 "currency": "USD",
                 "min_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400",
                 "max_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400"
             }
         ]
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the CarrierService API docs another read.

This part is used to SET UP your carrier service; usually when the merchant installs your app:

https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/carrierservice#create

Then, assuming the store has the CarrierServices API permissions, Shopify will send you something like the following, when a customer is going through checkout:

```
    {
       "rate": {
           "origin": {
               "country": "CA",
               "postal_code": "K1S4J3",
               "province": "ON",
               "city": "Ottawa",
               "name": null,
               "address1": "520 Cambridge Street South",
               "address2": null,
               "address3": null,
               "phone": null,
               "fax": null,
               "address_type": null,
               "company_name": null
           },
           "destination": {
               "country": "CA",
               "postal_code": "K1S 3T7",
               "province": "ON",
               "city": "Ottawa",
               "name": "Jason Normore",
               "address1": "520 Cambridge Street South Apt. 5",
               "address2": null,
               "address3": null,
               "phone": "7097433959",
               "fax": null,
               "address_type": null,
               "company_name": null
           },
           "items": [
               {
                   "name": "My Product 3",
                   "sku": null,
                   "quantity": 1,
                   "grams": 1000,
                   "price": 2000,
                   "vendor": "TestVendor",
                   "requires_shipping": true,
                   "taxable": true,
                   "fulfillment_service": "manual"
               }
           ],
           "currency": "CAD"
       }
    }
```

Note that it's not a regular _POST, rather a stream - with PHP you access that by:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

.. you use THAT to calculate your rates, then return them in the format:

```
    {
       "rates": [
           {
               "service_name": "canadapost-overnight",
               "service_code": "ON",
               "total_price": "1295",
               "currency": "CAD",
               "min_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400",
               "max_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400"
           },
           {
               "service_name": "fedex-2dayground",
               "service_code": "2D",
               "total_price": "2934",
               "currency": "USD",
               "min_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400",
               "max_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400"
           },
           {
               "service_name": "fedex-priorityovernight",
               "service_code": "1D",
               "total_price": "3587",
               "currency": "USD",
               "min_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400",
               "max_delivery_date": "2013-04-12 14:48:45 -0400"
           }
       ]
    }
```

.. and as long as the checkout hasn't timed out, the customer should see the rates returned.